# ruby on rails manually setting database and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ror, I have setup a new rails app on my shared server. According to the guide I should run `rake db:create` however I cannot because it is hosted on a server. Is there any way I can do it manually? i.e. by editing files?

Update:
Or may be developing the whole app on my system and copying all the files to the server?
there must be some way!
something like http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2011/07/deployment-from-rubymine-sync-files-via-ftpsftp-etc/ it works? I mean I do coding on my system and upload using rubymine and runs the server?

Comment: If you're trying to deploy rails app to a server to which you don't have SSH connection, you're in for a lot of pain.

Comment: Rails (or any other framework) applications aren't supposed to be copy/pasted using FTP. A SSH access is a must have.

Comment: what about this http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2011/07/deployment-from-rubymine-sync-files-via-ftpsftp-etc/

Comment: Well, just try it. ;) -- You'll need a SSH access sooner or later anyway. Also, since you are new to Ruby, you might want to give Heroku a try ; it's far less a pain for deployments.

Comment: no I'm not new to ruby, I'm new to ror :) and thnx.

Comment: @pahnin Since you are not ruby you can give `capistrano` a try write script in `capistrano` script and just run and leave rest to `capistrano`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you should use something very specialized with Ruby/Rails apps like Heroku.com ( which has a free version ) or get something where you have SSH access.